# Disabling interactivePopGestureRecognizer in iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have an app where I need to disable the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` so my custom slide menu does not show up. I think I might have pretty much tried everything that was mentioned in SO with no luck. My `.h` includes `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and in my `.m` file, I have the following code which was mentioned in quite a few questions. But it does not seem to work in `iOS 8 (I am running 8.3)`. One other thing I have noticed is that the delegate method `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` gets called but has no effect.

Does anybody know or have found a solution for this? As always, thanks for your help in advance. FYI, this code works fine in iOS7.

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        }
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
           }
    }

    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
    {
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this that worked? I'm having the same problem and nothing I see on SO is working.

Answer (score 2):

I found that setting `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO` works on iOS 8.3, but only if performed in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Re-enable by setting the property to `YES` in `viewWillDisappear`.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you have used navigation controller as your root view controller in app delegate file.

in that case put this code in applicationdidfinishlaunching

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```